# ArrayList turn becomes when an app is resumes after onKill in android

Tags: android, arraylist

My arraylist becomes null after restarting the app i.e after onKill.

I have declared the array list as Private

I dnt know what is the problem please help .

I have used shared preferences But somehow that dosnt help as welll

When i close the app/kill  and restart the arraylist becomes null

```
private    ArrayList<String>  PlacardHolder = new ArrayList<String>();
    private   ArrayList<String>  SecondaryPlacardArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private   ArrayList<String>  DangerousGoodsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private   ArrayList<String> Existing_placards= new ArrayList<String>();

    private int PlacardHolderRemainingslots = 2;
    private  int PlacardHolderPositions=0;
    private  int PrimaryPlacardCount=0;
    private  int SecondaryPlacardCount=0;
    private boolean Flag_Dangerous_placard_Existing=false;



    //String[] PrimaryPlacardArray=new String[3];

    private  int DangerousGoodsArrayCount=0;
    private static int CommonCount=0;


    int PrimaryConditionCount=0;
    //to take the positions of the placards in the placard holder so that it can be replaced 
    //Array to store position of placards in the position holder
    int[] NoOfPrimaryCount= new  int [3];
    int count=0;
    private localization localLanguage;

public static String filename="MySharedString";
SharedPreferences PlacardHolderData;
SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit;





    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        PlacardHolderData=getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);



///Adding to the placard code in between...Its quite big



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        //    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menu.add(menu.NONE,menu_undo,menu.NONE, localization.Menu_Items_Undo_Last);
        menu.add(menu.NONE,menu_placards,menu.NONE, localization.Menu_Items_Show_Placard);
        menu.add(menu.NONE,menu_dall,menu.NONE,localization.Menu_Items_Deliver_All);
        menu.add(menu.NONE,menu_delete,menu.NONE,localization.Menu_Items_Delete);
        menu.add(menu.NONE,info,menu.NONE,"Info");//localization reqired
        menu.add(menu.NONE,change_locale,menu.NONE,localization.Menu_change_locale);
        menu.add(menu.NONE,menu_office,menu.NONE,localization.Menu_Items_Sync_With_Office);
        menu.add(menu.NONE,menu_trackSettings,menu.NONE,"Track Settings");//localization reqired
        menu.add(menu.NONE,menu_quit,menu.NONE,localization.Menu_Items_Quit);


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // undo last item from list
        case menu_undo:
            try {
                String idUndo = Utils.idForUndo.get("idUndo");
                Log.e(TAG," Utils ids size  " +  Utils.idForUndo.size() );
                for(int i = 0; i < Utils.Placard_Detailss.size(); i++ )

                {
                    Log.e(TAG," placards hash map content " +  Utils. Placard_Detailss.get(idUndo));
                    Log.e(TAG," placards hash map content " +  Utils. Placard_Detailss.get(Utils. Placard_Detailss.get(idUndo) ));

                }



                if (idUndo != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "idUndo--> "+idUndo);
                    UpdateDBData ud = new UpdateDBData(getApplicationContext());
                    ud.undoLast(idUndo);            

                    ArrayList<String>   Placard_Details_Undo= new ArrayList<String>(Utils.Placard_Details_for_undo); 
                    Log.e(TAG,"pLACARD DETAILS FOR UNDO sixze"+ Utils.Placard_Details_for_undo.size());

                    for(int i = 0; i <Placard_Details_Undo.size();i++)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG,"pLACARD DETAILS FOR UNDO"+Placard_Details_Undo.get(i));
                    }

                    undoLastPlacard(  Utils. Placard_Detailss.get(idUndo) , Utils. Placard_Detailss.get(Utils. Placard_Detailss.get(idUndo) ) );

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,localization.Undo_last_message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                getBannerData();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                //
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
            // show all placards that are selected
        case menu_placards:
            try {



//               PlacardHolderData=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
//                sEdit= PlacardHolderData.edit();
// 
//              ArrayList<String> myAList=new ArrayList<String>();  
//               int size = PlacardHolderData.getInt("size", 0);
//               PlacardHolderData=getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
//               Log.e(TAG, "size" + size); 
//              
//               for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
//               {
//                 myAList.add(PlacardHolderData.getString("val"+j, "No Data"));
//               }                       
//               
//               Log.e(TAG, "size" + size);                          
//               
                 for(int j=0;j< PlacardHolder.size();j++)
                 {
                      Log.e(TAG, "Alist" + PlacardHolder.get(j));                        

                 }      

                if (PlacardHolder.size() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,localization.Sorry_No_Items_to_Show,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }

                alconvert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, null);
                alconvert.setView(convertView);
                TextView titleSAll = new TextView(this);
                titleSAll.setText(localization.Placards_on_the_Truck);
                titleSAll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                titleSAll.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                titleSAll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                titleSAll.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                titleSAll.setTextSize(20);
                alconvert.setCustomTitle(titleSAll);
                CustomAdapterShowAllPlacards myAdptShowAll = new CustomAdapterShowAllPlacards(PlacardHolder,MainActivity.this);
                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                lv.setAdapter(myAdptShowAll);
                alconvert.setButton(localization.Dialog_Ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alconvert.show();

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                //
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

return true;

Comment: Question is unclear.Please post your code & LogCat outputs

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you killed your app or finish your activity all the object created into the heap is cleaned by the garbage collector. so after killing your app or finish your activity your array list object is not available into the heap memory. so when u access it it always gives you null value.

so you need to again initialized array list reference variable. to do it :-

you need to store all the arrayList value into the cache or into the data base. and after storing it into the cache or database. then initialize the arrayList reference from cache or data base.

Comment: can i use OnSavedInstanceState and On Restore Instance state to save the arraylist on recreate of the application

Comment: No, because when u killed  your app your app data which u store in savedInstanceState or onRestore also destroyed. that why You can't save the data into savedInstanceState or onRestore.